# mysql- error 1054: unknown column 'album_id' in 'from clause'

Tags: mysql

`mysql> SELECT CONCAT(artist_name, " recorded ",      album_name) AS recording
    -> FROM album INNER JOIN artist USING (artist_id)
    -> ORDER BY recording;`

the above code runs successfully, but I am trying to get a full understanding of the lines. I wanted to know what is difference if INNER JOIN using album_id, or does it have to be artist_id.
so I tried the following:

`->  FROM album INNER JOIN artist USING (album_id);` 
and 
   `FROM artist INNER JOIN album USING (album_id);`

and then I got the errors. `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'album_id' in 'from clause'`

One additional question: what is a 'from clause'?

I just started playing around MySql, there might be dumb questions later on but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `USING(column)` requires the column to be existing in both tables.. A other more common INNER JOIN statement is like this  `.... table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id)`. Making your query more of less `SELECT CONCAT(artist_name, " recorded ",      album_name) AS recording FROM album INNER JOIN artist ON album.id = artist.album_id ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means `album_id` is not present in `album/artist` tables.

The use of `USING` clause is similar to `ON` clause. This is used to compare 2 tables on a preferred column which exists in both the tables.

If you can check, `artist_id` is present in both tables, but not `album_id` . So its giving you an error.

Comment: when I do `SELECT *FROM album`, the columns are artist_id, album_id, and album_name. For artist table, the columns are artist_id and artist_name, I am thinking maybe it is because they both share a common column "artist_id"

Comment: Yes, that is it. There is no `album_id` in table `artist`.  You must have column in both tables, to make a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just realized that table artist and album they share a column namely artist_id, that's why when they INNER JOIN, it got to be by artist_id.